# TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL REPEATABLE READ in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, biztalk, isolation-level

What are the risks or performance degradation when using SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL REPEATABLE READ?

We have some SP that are called from BizTalk services. We are getting deadlock sometimes. If we change the isolation level, what are the risks and possible perfomance degradations?

Comment: What do you mean by "deadlocks"? Is is that `SQL Server` returns an error message saying that a deadlock had been resolved, or you transactions just hang? The latter is not a deadlock, it's a lock contention.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Repeatable Read will put locks on all rows that have
been fetched. In situations where you are working with
cursors fetching large amounts of data this can cause
contention with other users because they cannot
obtain locks to update any of the rows read by cursors
with Repeatable Read until the cursor is closed.

The risk of performance degradation is that transactions may
suffer an increased number of timeouts and/or deadlocks. This risk
is proportional to the probability that two transactions need to
read/update the same rows at the same time. Another factor that
can impact your application is the size of lock taken. If locks are
taken at a page level then contention may occur if the data different
transactions need to access lie on the same page - not necessarily the same row.

On the other hand, when you use a lower isolation level,
cursor stability for example, you leave open the possibility
that rows you have previously fetched during your transaction may be
updated by other transactions before your unit of work has
completed.

Answer (score 2):

Try it. There is no way we can tell you what potential risks or performance issues you might run into with a single data point (TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL). We know NOTHING else about your data, data volume, TPS, data dependencies. Whenever performance is a question, try it, measure it. There is no other answer.

Answer (score 2):

To add to what has been said already: You can't eliminate deadlocks altogether. All you can do is minimize the likelyhood for them to happen.

Answer (score 1):

Repeatable read does not lift shared locks after the reads had been made.

This means that if you performed a `SELECT` in a `RR` transaction, the concurrent transactions will not be able to update the rows locked by your `SELECT`.